# Check if characters in a firstname String contain at least 1 digit

Tags: java, string

I try to check if characters in a firstname String contain at least 1 digit, if yes ask to the user to input it again and then going back to the loop and check again but with a GoTo break it only works the first time and won't loop it again. Oh and I do this from a method with a String array of more than only a first name in it. Isn't the break GoTo supposed to bring me back to my label and then do the loop over again looking for a digit?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    infoInputGathering();
}
public static String[] infoInputGathering(){
    String[] infos = new String[3]; // Declaration of the infos String array
    boolean isStringOnly;
    char[] characterChecker;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Creation of the Scanner object input
    // Asking the user to input their first name and stores it in a String Array info[0]
    System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
    infos[0] = input.next();
    characterChecker = infos[0].toCharArray();
    
    firstname:
    for (int c = 0 ; c<=characterChecker.length ; ++c ) {
        if (Character.isDigit(characterChecker[c])) {
            System.out.println("A first name should not contain any number...");
            System.out.print("Enter your first name without a number: ");
            infos[0] = input.next();
            characterChecker = infos[0].toCharArray();
            Break firstname;
        }
    }
```

Final Full Code I came up with with Ali's help on this part

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class InfiniteInfoGatheringUntilStop {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int iterationsCounter = 0; // Declares/Initiate a counter for the loops
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Creation of the Scanner object input

    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(); // Creates an ArrayList for the names inputs
    ArrayList<String> birth = new ArrayList<String>(); // Creates an ArrayList for the date of birth inputs
    ArrayList<String> gpa = new ArrayList<String>(); // Creates an ArrayList for the GPA inputs

    while(true){ // Always true loop unless break out on if conditions

        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        names.add(input.next());
        //Code to check if there are numerical character in the String of the listArray inputted
        char[] characterChecker = names.get(iterationsCounter).toCharArray(); //Declare and initiates an array of character from the ArrayList names(iterationsCounter)
        int c = 0;
        while(true){ // Loop to check every character and asks for a retype if detects one character as numerical
            if(Character.isDigit(characterChecker[c])){
                System.out.println("A first name should not contain any number...");
                System.out.print("Enter your first name without a number: ");
                names.set(iterationsCounter,input.next());
                characterChecker = names.get(iterationsCounter).toCharArray();
                c = 0;
            }
            else {
                c++;
            }
            if(c == characterChecker.length){
                break;
            }
        }
        if(names.get(iterationsCounter).equalsIgnoreCase("stop")){ //Checks if stop has been typed, breaks in that case but erases previous ArrayLists of this cycle
            names.remove(iterationsCounter);
            break;
        }
        System.out.print("Enter your date of birth in this format AAAAmmdd: ");
        birth.add(input.next());
        characterChecker = birth.get(iterationsCounter).toCharArray(); //Declare and initiates an array of character from the ArrayList names(iterationsCounter)
        c = 0;
        while(true){ // Loop to check every character and asks for a retype if detects one character as letter
            if(characterChecker.length != 8){ // Checks for a maximum length of 8 characters
                System.out.println("A date of birth in the right format (AAAAmmdd) please...");
                System.out.print("Reenter your date of birth again (AAAAmmdd): ");
                birth.set(iterationsCounter,input.next());
                characterChecker = birth.get(iterationsCounter).toCharArray();
            }
            else if(Character.isLetter(characterChecker[c])){ //checkes if there are letters in the characters
                System.out.println("A date of birth in the right format (AAAAmmdd) please...");
                System.out.print("Reenter your date of birth again (AAAAmmdd): ");
                birth.set(iterationsCounter,input.next());
                characterChecker = birth.get(iterationsCounter).toCharArray();
                c = 0;
            }
            else {
                c++;
            }
            if(c == characterChecker.length){ //breaks when c = to the length meaning all characters have been checked through the loop

                break;
            }
        }
        if(birth.get(iterationsCounter).equalsIgnoreCase("stop")){ //Checks if stop has been typed, breaks in that case but erases previous ArrayLists of this cycle
            names.remove(iterationsCounter);
            birth.remove(iterationsCounter);
            break;
        }

        System.out.print("Enter your GPA in 0.0 format: ");
        gpa.add(input.next());
        characterChecker = gpa.get(iterationsCounter).toCharArray(); //Declare and initiates an array of character from the ArrayList names(iterationsCounter)
        c = 0;
        while(true){ // Loop to check every character and asks for a retype if detects one character as letter
            if(characterChecker.length != 3){ // Checkes for a maximum length of 8 characters
                System.out.println("A GPA in the right format please (0.0)...");
                System.out.print("Reenter your GPA please: ");
                gpa.set(iterationsCounter,input.next());
                characterChecker = gpa.get(iterationsCounter).toCharArray();
            }
            else if(Character.isLetter(characterChecker[c])){ //checks if there are digits in the characters
                System.out.println("A GPA in the right format please (0.0)...");
                System.out.print("Reenter your GPA: ");
                gpa.set(iterationsCounter,input.next());
                characterChecker = gpa.get(iterationsCounter).toCharArray();
                c = 0;
            }

            else {
                c++;
            }
            if(c == characterChecker.length){ //breaks when c = to the length meaning all characters have been checked through the loop

                break;
            }
        }
        if(gpa.get(iterationsCounter).equalsIgnoreCase("stop")){ //Checks if stop has been typed, breaks in that case but erases previous ArrayLists of this cycle
            names.remove(iterationsCounter);
            birth.remove(iterationsCounter);
            gpa.remove(iterationsCounter);
            break;
        }
        iterationsCounter++; // Incrementes the counter if a full loop is done
    }

    // Prints the results
    System.out.println("Number of valid inputs before you got exhausted: " + iterationsCounter);
    System.out.println("====================================================================================");

    //A loop to print the content of the 3 ListArrays
    for(int arrayLoc = 0; arrayLoc < iterationsCounter; arrayLoc++){
        System.out.println((arrayLoc+1) + "-\t" + names.get(arrayLoc) +
                            "\t\t" + birth.get(arrayLoc) +
                            "\t\t" + gpa.get(arrayLoc));
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code with while loop like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] infos = new String[3];
        char[] characterChecker;
        System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
        infos[0] = input.next();
        characterChecker = infos[0].toCharArray();
        int c = 0;
        while(true){
            if (Character.isDigit(characterChecker[c])){
                 System.out.println("A first name should not contain any number...");
                 System.out.print("Enter your first name without a number: ");
                 infos[0] = input.next();
                 characterChecker = infos[0].toCharArray();
                 c = 0;
            }
            else
                 c++;
 
            if(c == characterChecker.length)
                 break;
        }
        System.out.println("Correct Name");
    }
}
```

If c is equal to characterChecker.length, ie in the name, there is no number, then it is correct and we break loop and print Correct Name.

Comment: Thank you. It help me reconsider how to use the break and the loop!